# Why are total kinetic energy and interaction energy roughly the same for a liquid?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, equilibrium, interactions, kinetic-theory

Let's say one has a collection of point particles, each with a kinetic energy and (e.g. Coulomb) repulsion between all of them.

Under certain conditions, the system will evolve to the stable state where the total kinetic energy equals the potential energy.

How can one analyze and understand this system? What are the conditions to achieve this state?

Comment: Can you cite an example? It seems similar to  Virial theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mum mentionned in the comment, the fact that your system will evolve to the stable state where the total kinetic energy equals the potential energy, has to do with the **[Virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem)**.

The theorem states that the time average of the total kinetic energy of a system is proportional to the time average of the work done in bringing all the particles from origin to the point where they are found at any instant of time,
\begin{equation*}
    \left\langle T\right\rangle =-{\frac {1}{2}}\,\sum _{k=1}^{N}{\bigl 
    \langle }\mathbf {F} _{k}\cdot \mathbf {r} _{k}{\bigr \rangle }
\end{equation*}
which is nothing more than the potential energy itself.